# ng-style does not work with nested object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how my code looks like

```
<md-button ng-style="connectivityColorFor({{ connection.org }})">{{  connection.skyhigh.api  }}</md-button>
```

On console, I see

```
connectivity:{"api":"connected","collector":"not_connected"}
```

but when I do

```
<md-button ng-style="connectivityColorFor({{ connection.org.api }})">{{  connection.skyhigh.api  }}</md-button>
```

I get

```
connectivity:undefined
```

and on `JS`, my code is

```
  $scope.connectivityColorFor = function(connectivity) {
    console.log('connectivity:' + JSON.stringify(connectivity));
    return {"background-color": connectivityTypes[connectivity]}
  }
  var connectivityTypes = {
    'connected': '#8BC34A',
    'not_configured': '#EF6C00',
    'not_connected': '#EF5350'
  }
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: How is your connection object looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for interpolation of the argument, the `ngStyle` directive `$eval`-s the entire expression against the scope. You should simply use

```
<md-button ng-style="connectivityColorFor(connection.org.api)"></md-button>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/40blRRJZ2CTfDZQFkLuT?p=preview) is a working simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Contectivity is a object, so if you write `connectivityTypes[connectivity]`
you'll get undefined.
You have to use `connectivity.someProperty` like:

```
    return {"background-color": connectivityTypes[connectivity.api]}
```